# LNK error 2001 while building wpa_supplicant

Tags: c, visual-studio-2005, wpa

I am trying to build wpa_supplicant application on Windows using VS2005. When I build it, I am getting a Link error:

```
------ Rebuild All started: Project: wpa_cli, Configuration: Release Win32 ------

Deleting intermediate and output files for project 'wpa_cli', configuration 'Release|Win32'

Compiling...  
wpa_ctrl.c  
wpa_cli.c  
os_win32.c  
common.c  

Linking...  

wpa_cli.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _eloop_init  
wpa_cli.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _eloop_unregister_read_sock  
wpa_cli.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _eloop_register_timeout  
wpa_cli.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _edit_redraw  
wpa_cli.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _edit_init  
wpa_cli.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol  _eloop_register_read_sock  
wpa_cli.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _eloop_destroy  
wpa_cli.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _eloop_terminate  
wpa_cli.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _eloop_register_signal_terminate  
wpa_cli.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _eloop_run  
wpa_cli.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _eloop_cancel_timeout  
wpa_cli.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _edit_deinit  
wpa_cli.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _edit_clear_line  

D:\Interworking\wpa_supplicant-1.0.tar\wpa_supplicant-1.0\wpa_supplicant-1.0
\wpa_supplicant\vs2005\Release\wpa_cli.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 13 unresolved externals
```

I have given additional Include directories where eloop_init, eloop_unregister_read_sock etc.. defined.

Answer (score 0):

Another common question:

In addition to the additional include directories(so your code can compile), you should also add the linked libraries(so your code can link): It should be in

> Project properties/Configuration properties/Linker/Input/Additional
>   Dependencies

In VS2010, it would be like:

[image]

Other versions of Visual Studio should be similar.

Comment: yes I have already added those lib through command line option.

Comment: /OUT:"D:\Interworking\wpa_supplicant-1.0.tar\wpa_supplicant-1.0\wpa_supplicant-1.0\wpa_supplicant\vs2005\Release\wpa_cli.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:"Release\wpa_cli.exe.intermediate.manifest" /DEBUG /PDB:"d:\interworking\wpa_supplicant-1.0.tar\wpa_supplicant-1.0\wpa_supplicant-1.0\wpa_supplicant\vs2005\release\wpa_cli.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /LTCG /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT ws2_32.lib  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib

Comment: @david it is not clear to me, but if you are sure you've add the lib, can you check if the directory to those lib is also set? which should be in *Project properties/Configuration properties/Linker/General/Additional Library Directories*

Comment: hi, I didnt properly set the source files path where the above i have mentioned functions are defined. I have added already in additional include directories with "..\..\..\src\utils". where files are present. VS 2005 only taking when it is added through adding source and header files into work space not error is causing. do you have any idea why those files are not taking when i have added through additional include directories ??

Comment: additional include directories is different from additional library directories - one for header include, one for library link